# Delphi Lockbox Hashing

Tags: delphi, encryption

I need to hash a string, preferably as SHA512, although it could be SHA256, SHA1, MD5 or CRC32.

I have downloaded Lockbox 3, put a TCryptographicLibrary and a THash component on a form, set the Hash property to SHA-512 and used the following code to produce a test result:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Hash1.HashString('myhashtest');
  Edit1.Text := Stream_To_AnsiString(Hash1.HashOutputValue);
end;
```

To best illustrate the problem, I have gone on to an online hash calculator and the MD5 hash of 'myhashtest' is `ff91e22313f0a41b46719e7ee6f99451` but setting the hash property in my test program to MD5 results in `ÿ‘â#ð¤Fqž~æù”Q` which is clearly wrong. I have tried the same test using other Hash properties, including the SHA512 which i want, and they all return rubbish.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What Delphi version? What online calculator? Can you include the link to it, so that we have something to test against?

Comment: Looks like it's base64 encoded.

Comment: Online result looks more like it's simply hex encoded rather than base64.

Comment: user3173083 - its customary to accept the correct answer by clicking the check mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`THash.HashOutputValue` is a stream of the raw hashed bytes. It appears that `Stream_To_AnsiString()` merely copies those raw bytes as-is into an `AnsiString`, it does not encode the bytes in any way. What you are looking for is the hex encoded version of the raw bytes instead. I do know that LockBox has a `Stream_To_Base64()` function (as shown in [this example](http://lockbox.seanbdurkin.id.au/tiki-index.php?page=Hash+something)), but I do not know if it has a `Stream_To_Hex()` type of function. If it does not, you can easily create your own, eg:

```
function Stream_To_Hex(Stream: TStream): AnsiString;
var
  NumBytes, I: Integer;
  B: Byte;
begin
  NumBytes := Stream.Size - Stream.Position;
  SetLength(Result, NumBytes * 2);
  for I := 0 to NumBytes-1 do
  begin
    Stream.ReadBuffer(B, 1);
    BinToHex(@B, @Result[(I*2)+1], 1);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Hash1.HashString('myhashtest');
  Edit1.Text := Stream_To_Hex(Hash1.HashOutputValue);
end;
```

Comment: The above `Stream_To_Hex` function does not work in Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update 1. What is wrong?

Comment: @user1580348 you need to be more specific. What is the actual problem you are having with it?

Answer (score 1):

Many cryptographic functions 'silently' (i.e. without stating so in the docs) output and require Base64- or hex-encoded strings (and also often AnsiStrings). This is because encrypted text can contain any data, and as soon as you start treating that as 'strings', string handling functions can easily choke on that (e.g. null-terminated strings containing a null). By Base-64/hex encoding the cryptotext you make sure it will be plain old ASCII characters that evene old code can read/write.

If you dig around a little in the cryptocode or its method parameters you usually can determine that, and convert your strings accordingly.

Comment: Thanks guys. Once the hash output was converted to hex, it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where stream_to_hex, it is inside uTPLB_StreamUtils (pas or hpp) depending if you are using c builder or delphi.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).